# Xampp Alternative to Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, xampp, getusermedia, server

I want to use the GetUserMedia API on an Ubuntu OS. The thing is this api for javascript only works when there is a server running(example-for windows I had to use xampp). Is there any way I can run a server on ubuntu to so I can use the api. I only have access the the commandline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is only a web server, then you just need to install apache from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Then host your static files from apache.

Comment: he will also need, `sudo apt-get install php5 mysql-client mysql-server